# I keep getting logged out when I try to login using ROBLOSECURITY token

Tags: python, roblox

I am using robloxpy and nextcord. I want to login to a roblox account to make a command, and host the discord bot on replit. But, roblox logs me out of my account as soon as I try to login using the ROBLOSECURITY token. I tried using requests to get the cookie after logging in using username and password:

```
data = {
  "ctype": "Username",
  "cvalue": "testusername",
  "password": os.environ['rblxpass'],
  "captchaToken": os.environ['captchatoken']
}


Headers = {
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

res =  requests.get("https://www.roblox.com/login", json=data, headers = Headers)
print(res.ok)
```

This code returns True, but I can't seem to get the token from it.

Is there any other way to get the token to work without roblox logging me out?
This is the code in my command:

```
    if user in getgroupmembers():
      rank = calcrank(user)
      roleid = listofrankids[rank]
      print(roleid)
      userid = robloxpy.User.External.GetID(user)
      print(userid)
      robloxpy.User.Groups.Internal.ChangeRank(groupid,userid,roleid)
      await ctx.send(f"Success! {user} now has the {rank} rank!")
```

The only way I found is to run the code on the same computer as the roblox account, but I want to host this code on replit. so I tried using requests. I am looking for a way to get the token from roblox ON the repl. (or if there is any other way)

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand how this security token would be different than any other session cookie out there, but if you're planning on persistence beteween requests, you're supposed to use `requests.Session()`. In that way you keep cookies inbetween requests. I am guessing you're getting logged out because subsequent requests do not contain the token, as you're not using a session.

Comment: Ok, so I logged into roblox using `requests.Session()`, but I can't seem to get the cookie. `r = s.request(url = "https://www.roblox.com/login",method = "GET", headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)` The response header only gives me the X-CSRF token, and the userid, not the cookie. Cookies is just an empty dictionary.